# PHP validation question

Tags: php

How do I check and see if a user enters only numbers and is at least 4 numbers long using PHP?

Comment: Please attempt to write your code first; http://www.php.net is a great reference.

Comment: @TaG, that seems a little uncalled for.

Comment: RTFQ folks! Lots of sloppy answers to this question for some reason.

Comment: @smotchkkiss, It was just a joke to an uncalled comment :)

Comment: @TaG, it might be worth seeing the benchmarks I provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
/^\d{4,}$/
```

Example usage:

```
$s = "7325";
if (preg_match('/^\d{4,}$/', $s)) {
    echo "matches";
}
```

Comment: Which you can check using `preg_match()`

Comment: one thing people often forget when using `$` is that it also matches a new line just before end, so the above will validate `"7325\n"`. To work around this, use D modifier, or `\z` instead of dollar.

Answer (score 6):

Mark Byers' suggestion is good, but here's another way:

```
$valid = ctype_digit($number) && strlen($number) >= 4;
```

Comment: I like this because (like Mark's) '0123' meets the condition and regex engine is not used.

Comment: @notJim, you win my vote because yours in the most performant :)

Answer (score 1):

## ctype_digit() && strlen() wins

```
<?php

function benchmark($callback){
  echo sprintf('%-30s: ', $callback);
  $t = microtime(true);
  foreach(range(1, 10000) as $n){
    call_user_func($callback);
  }
  echo (microtime(true)-$t)."\n";
}

function mark_byers_preg_match(){
  $s = "7325";
  preg_match('/^\d{4,}$/', $s);
}

function notjim_ctype_digit_strlen(){
  $number = 7325;
  ctype_digit($number) && strlen($number) >= 4;
}

function tomalak_intval_broken(){
  $check = 7325;
  intval($check) == $check && $check >= 1000 && $check <= 9999;
}

benchmark('mark_byers_preg_match');
benchmark('notjim_ctype_digit_strlen');
benchmark('tomalak_intval_broken');

?>
```

## results

```
mark_byers_preg_match         : 0.029040098190308
notjim_ctype_digit_strlen     : 0.026585817337036
tomalak_intval_broken         : 0.019872903823853
```

**Note:** @Tomalak's does not work with numbers starting with `0` so it does not qualify

---

**Edit:** @kiethjgrant's solution was removed because `intval(0000)` evaluates as `false` when it should be `true`.

Comment: with numbers this close by, there is no winner. Also, since the OP said, this is user input, all input will be strings.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but this is the mother of all pointless, premature micro-optimizations.

Comment: @notJim, both "mother of all pointless" and "premature" are moot points.  Sometimes the results are drastically different, and it only took about 2 minutes to copy/paste the solutions into the script. What's the harm?

Comment: What I mean is that with a difference of .003 seconds for 10000 trials, choosing either option based on these results would be foolish.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any example code to start with?

To strictly answer your question, you could use a regex like `if(preg_match('/^\d{4,}$/', $input)...`.

But there's a lot more to consider here: you need to consider both validation and filtering (and you're best to keep the two separate issues).  If you're strictly checking for an integer, then I suppose you're safe from SQL injection, XSS, etc., but you really need to have a handle on those issues, because sooner or later you're going to need to filter & validate something other than a simple integer.

Comment: intval('0000') is 0, which would be invalid by yours, even though it's four digits and has length 4 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

you should always use the most efficient way to do it

```
if ( is_numeric($imput) && isset($input[3]) )
{
  // your code
}
```

isset() is a language construct, which is always faster than strlen().

isset($input[n-1]) tells you whether string(data which passes through form is always string) has at least n long.

is_numeric() checks it is a valid num string.

i think it is better than ctype_digit() && strlen().

Comment: is_numeric validates much more then just digits.